# Total Order Relation

Tags: relations, order-theory

Given $X = \{ a , b , c \}$ and $R = \{ (a,a) , (b,b) , (c,c) , (a,b) , (a,c)\}$

*Is $R$ a total order on $X$?*

I know that total order requires the relation to be comparable on all elements, anti-symmetric, and transitive.

What I am confused about is that I was told this relation is NOT total order, but I do not see how the elements **cannot be compared**, because they surely are **anti-symmetric** and **transitive**.

Can't $a$ be compared to itself? Surely $(a,b)$ and $(a,c)$ pass the comparability test, so all that remains must be the reflexive examples.

Clarification is greatly appreciated, thank you for your time, patience and assistance!

Comment: I don't think you correctly grasp the concept of comparability. For instance $b$ and $c$ aren't comparable. Can you understand why?

Comment: Are b and c incomparable because there is no element in which they are relate-able such as (b,c) or (c,b)? And I am inferring then that every element must be comparable, in this case b and c, which make it not total order. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The first part is correct, $b$ and $c$ are incomparable because neither $(b,c)$, nor $(c,b)$ are in $R$. The second part I don't really understand, but it seems you have the right idea.

Answer (score 6):

A total order relation requires 4 things:
1)refxivity(it is reflexive in this case)
2)anti-symmetricity(it is anti-symmetric) 
3)transitivity(it is transitive)
4)comparibility
Now compatibility means that if you choose any two elements say a,b then either aRb or bRa
But in this case if we take for example b and c, neither bRc nor cRb so the relation is not compatible and hence is not a total order.

Comment: This is not true of a strict order relation like $(\mathbb Z, <)$.  Strict total orders are by definition, irreflexive, and comparable to every element, in my example, every *other* element, in $\mathbb Z$.  So the set of intergers under the strict total order of $<$, we have $-1\lt n \forall n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$ and we have for every $m$, $m\in \{\ldots, -4, -3, -2\}$, $m\lt -1$.

Comment: I meant it is not true of a strict total order.

Answer (score -6):

Is this relation transitive?. I don't think so.
We have (a,b) and (a,c). 
To be transitive, (b,c) must be a part of relation too. 
So, this is not a total order relation because is not transitive.

Comment: That's not the definition of transitivity: That would be the case if $(b,a)$ and $(a,c)$ were in $R$. In fact, that relation *is* a partial order, hence transitive.